# forward ssh port from one host to another host and different port on another interface

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

i would like to forward a ssh port to another host and a different port and interface.

server1:22 -> server1:22

public internet -> eth0 -> server1:23 -> eth1 -> server2:22

i enabled ipv4 forwarding

```
sysctl -p
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

and created the following ip table rules

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 23 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.3:22
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 23 -j ACCEPT
```

but i can't get it to work, what am i missing?

---

finaly with haukes help i got it to work

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d <Server1_eth0> -p tcp --dport 2223 -j MARK --set-mark 1 -i eth0
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m mark --mark 1 -j DNAT --to-destination <Server2>:2222 -i eth0
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m mark  --mark 1 -j SNAT --to-source <Server1_eth1> -o eth1 
iptables -A FORWARD -m mark --mark 1 -j ACCEPT -o eth1

where Server1_eth0 is my public ip
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If server1 is not the gateway for server2 then you need SNAT, too. Otherwise server2 will send the reply to the client which doesn't recognize the packet as it doesn't have server1 as source address but server2.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT --ctorigdst server1 --ctorigdstport 23 -j SNAT --to-source server1
```

A precise and easy to understand filter criteria for the rules in FORWARD, PREROUTING and POSTROUTING would be a packet mark:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d $server1_ip -p tcp --dport 23 -j MARK --set-mark 22
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m mark --mark 22 -j DNAT --to-destination $server2_ip:22
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 22 -j SNAT --to-source $server1_ip
iptables -A FORWARD -m mark --mark 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Please note: If server1 has more than one interface and the DNATed packets are routed from one interface to another (like it turned out in this case) then the destination match IP and the SNAT IP are different.

"-p tcp" should not be necessary in the second line but iptables or Netfilter requires it. It may be useful to add e.g. `-m comment --comment "DNAT SSH from port 23 to server2"` in all lines to make the optput of `iptables -L -nv` easier to understand.

Comment: so i should add this to the other 2 rules i've already got? do i have to set --ctorigdst ?

Comment: Sure you have to add this. The command does what's needed in less complex variants. Ijust felt like looking up how to do it "the right way". `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING \! -d server2  -j SNAT --to-source server1` would do the same but may (depending on the circumstances) match more packets than the DNATed ones for SSH. That can be a problem but is not necessarily one. I have an idea for a clearer solution, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: i added  "iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT --ctorigdst 192.168.0.2 --ctorigdstport 23 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.3" to the 2 rules which i posted above and also tried to-source 192.168.0.3:22 but haven't had any success so far.

Comment: Have a look at the traffic with tcpdump. What is the problem, does the SNAT rule not match?

Comment: sorry i forget to mention that i have 2 interfaces, traffic comes in at eth0 and should leave at eth1, since eth0 is connected to the internet and eth1 is connected to a private network. at the first two rules i added -i eth0 and at the last two i added -o eth1, if i listen with tcpdump -i eth1 dst 192.168.0.3 where the ssh connection should be routed to i get ARP, Request who-has a1c tell a1f - i edited my question.

Comment: @supernova Can you ping server2 from server1?

Comment: yes,i can also connect from s2 to s1 with ssh on its private ip.

Comment: i posted my rules here http://paste.debian.net/238607/, i'm not sure about the first line you wrote with -m conntrack, this refers to my original question?

Comment: @supernova a1c is the server2 IP and a1f is the private server1 IP? If you have just pinged then there should be no ARP requests. Please check again with tcpdump after pinging. Strange situation.

Comment: @supernova Your rules are wrong (or at least critical). The mark number can be whatever you like but port numbers 2223 (original target) and 2222 (DNAT target) are correct? A definite problem is that you have mixed public and private IPs. You SNAT to $publicip. This may work but does not make much sense and should be avoided unless you really know what you are doing. SNAT to your private IP instead.

Comment: okay, i will look into it again, i appreciate your help, should i also add the port at the SNAT rule at --to-source or just the ip?

Comment: ahh got it working.. thanks very much, would upvote your answer 100 times if i could :)

Comment: @supernova There are more answers by me elsewhere :-)  Even about the same subject (it's quite "popular"). I like my mark proposal. I will probably use this answer as reference in the future.

Comment: yea i can understand why, iptables is such a powerfull tool and it's kinda difficult to get into it, i read a few tutorials but most of them are very basic. thank you again, i spent nearly 2 days on this before asking here :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7693/discussion-between-supernova-and-hauke-laging)